# ¿ Cómo realizar una búsqueda y mostrar el resultado?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quisiera realizar una búsqueda a la base de datos, que el cliente ingrese el nombre del punto y que le arroje el resultado. En mi proyecto tengo la vista index donde se están mostrando todos registros de mi BD y el formulario buscar.

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end p-2 point-form">
    <%= form_tag points_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :point, params[:point] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Buscar", name: nil %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div class="row border border-bottom bg-light shadow rounded">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="points">
      <% @point.each do |point| %>
      <div class="point clearfix">
        <div class="point-details">
           <span class="point-title"><%= link_to point.name, point %></span>
           <span class="point-description"><%= point.ccosto %></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por lo que he leído en las guia de [RubyonRails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-form-for-and-form-tag) lo cual he entendido muy poco... ya que tiene helpers para realizar el formulario (esa parte esta clara), ya realizado el formulario, se tiene que pasar la la ruta donde se va a realizar la consulta, ya desde ese parte no etniendo mucho... por eso he venido hasta aquí para que porfavor me ayuden a entender un poco y así poder superar esta meta.

Este es el modelo:

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, presence: true;
  validates :ccosto, presence: true;
  validates :tecnologia, presence: true;
  validates :observacion, presence: true;
  validates :ipradio, presence: true;
  validates :iptele, presence: true;
  validates :ipcom, presence: true;
end
```

Este es el controlador:

```
    class PointsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :private_access

      def index
        @point = Point.all
      end

      def new
        @point = Point.all
      end

      def create
        @point = Point.new(point_params)
        @point.user = current_user
        if @point.save
          redirect_to points_path, notice: "El punto fue Ingresado con éxito"
        else
         render :new
        end
      end

      def show
        @point = Point.find(params[:id])
      end

      def edit
        @point = Point.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        point = Point.find(params[:id])
        if point.update(point_params)
          redirect_to points_path, notice: "El punto fue modificado con exito"
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end

      def destroy
        point = Point.find(params[:id])
        point.destroy

        redirect_to points_path, notice: "El punto fue eliminado con exito"
      end

      private
        def point_params
        params.require(:point).permit(:name, :ccosto, :tecnologia, :observacion, :ipradio, :iptele, :ipcom)
      end

    end
```

Gracias

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a S.O.es. ¿podrías agregar a tu pregunta qué es exactamente lo que no has entendido de la guía de rails? creo que sería un buen punto de partida. Si consideras que es relevante, también agrega la información del controlador y modelo involucrado en tu búsqueda de points. Si te está arrojando un error o información en el log que sea relevante, también agrégala. Saludos

Comment: Hola Alter, Gracias por la bienvenida a S.O.es. He atendido tus sugerencias y he actualizado la pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, la información que agregaste da más contexto, pero aun no estoy seguro 100% sobre tu problema, así que iré por lo que entiendo.
Sé que quieres buscar los point a través de `text_field_tag :point, params[:point]`, pero no explicas la naturaleza de tu búsqueda, si quieres buscar los points por `:name`, `:ccosto`, `:tecnologia`, etc., si quieres buscar por más de un campo, si el campo a buscar debe tener el valor exacto o si debería ser parte de una cadena más grande (usando SQL `LIKE`).
La búsqueda claramente deberías hacerla en el `index` action de tu controlador. En sus términos más básicos, debería ser algo como esto:

```
  def index
    # En caso que venga un término de búsqueda como parámetro, lo deberás usar
    # en tu búsqueda
    if params[:point]
      # puse buscar por name, que es lo más básico, pero claramente esto
      # cambiará dependiendo de la naturaleza de tu búsqueda o definiendo qué en
      # realidad quieres buscar.
      @point = Point.where(name: params[:point]) 
    else
      # si no viene un point, entonces cargas todo, igual a como está ahora.
      @point = Point.all
    end
  end
```

Comment: Me disculparas por no entender de mucho, el campo buscar lo realize con los helpers de rails que encontre en la documentacion de la misma, por lo anterior me base en eso y para colocar `text_field_tag :point, paras[:point]` ya que `text_field_tag` genera un `input` pero en realidad no entiendo mucho como fucnionan los demas parametros. Si tiene algun conociento de alguna web donde expliquen esa parte seria de gran ayuda. Por otro lado he ingresado su codigo me da error al realizar la busqueda `Unsupported argument type: name (Symbol)` en esta linea `@point = Point.where(:name, params[:point])`

Comment: La línea que te da error la escribiste distinto a lo que puse. No sabría decirte de algún tutorial, en general cuando tengo una duda, con las guías oficiales de rails me basta y sobra. No entiendo a que te refieres con que no sabes como funcionan los demás parámetros, ¿a qué parámetros te refieres? En gral. el código de la vista veo que está correcto para realizar una búsqueda.